# Keras model.evaluate returns different MAE than sklearn's function

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

When I train the model I use MAE as the metric:

```
my_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['mae'])
```

After training the model, I predict on the test set and use sklearn's mean_absolute_error function to find the MAE on the test set:

```
    def test(self):
        preds = self.model.predict(self.xtest)
        pred_int = [np.argmax(x) - 2 for x in preds]
        mae = mean_absolute_error(self.ytest, pred_int)
        print("Sklearn MAE: {}".format(mae))
```

This outputs:

```
Sklearn MAE: 1.6824460780353825
```

However, when I use Keras's evaluate function, I get a different number:

```
score = self.model.evaluate(x=self.xtest,y=self.y_cat_test)
print("model.evaluate MAE on test set: {}".format(score[1]))
```

Where

```
self.y_cat_test = to_categorical(self.ytest, num_classes=params['num_cat'])
```

Which outputs:

```
model.evaluate MAE on test set: 0.30854440440807257
```

I attempted to create a custom metric so I wrote the following function:

```
def MY_METRIC(self, y_true, y_pred):
    x = np.abs(y_pred - y_true)
    return x
```

When I use this as a metric for the model, it returns the same numbers as Keras's MAE function. The problem is, the function above isn't MAE.

[Wikipedia page on MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)

When I change the custom metric to the reflect the MAE equation

```
 def MY_METRIC(self, y_true, y_pred):
        x = np.average(np.abs(y_pred - y_true))
        return x
```

I get the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?